# Centering numbered equations

Tags: equations, journal

I am writing a document using the BioMed Central style.

I have to insert some equations, which I would like to number.

For example I wrote:

```
\begin{equation}
\hat{a} = aV_kV_k^T
\end{equation}
```

but I got this result:
[image]

The math part is on the left-side. How can I center it?

Comment: Are you using some `leqno` option somewhere on preamble?

Comment: I suspect that the BioMed Central style uses the fleqn option somewhere implicitly or explicitly.  You can use the gather environment (of amsmath) instead of equation to get what you want.

Comment: If that is the journal style, then *do not* change it, you will just end up annoying the journal editors. Editors see this a lot, authors how does not like the journal style and then change it to something they like. But the layout it *not* your decision, it is the publisher/journal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, when writing a document to be published in a journal, changing the journal style is highly **unrecommended**.

The reason that equations are positioned at a fixed indent from the left margin in the BioMed Central style is that the [BioMed Central class](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex) redefines some of the math environments and passes the option `fleqn` to `amsmath`. To get centered equations, just remove the line

> `\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}`

in the file `bmcart.cls` and load the `amsmath` package in your `.tex` file.